# Cordova file management, is this correct way of doing it

Tags: javascript, cordova

I am making a application using Phonegap where users can select and share files. When user selects it even if goes offline or close the app I should upload it back to the server, so I need to store reference file path. So below are steps and code I have used

1. User selects/captures video or image using Camera.
2. File may not contain extension to name in Android every time and in iOS when selected from Gallery.
3. So get mimeType and then copy the file to myApp's folder with a new name and extension.
4. Then again get mimeType and return.

But my question is also, whether is it correct to copy file and another location whenever user selects a media file.

**Code**

```
 var obj = {
    destinationType: navigator.camera.DestinationType[fromCamera ? 'FILE_URI' : 'NATIVE_URI'],
    // If I use NATIVE_URI for when taking from Camera it returns null.
    sourceType: navigator.camera.PictureSourceType[fromCamera ? 'CAMERA' : 'PHOTOLIBRARY'],
    mediaType: navigator.camera.MediaType[image ? 'PICTURE' : 'VIDEO']
}, that = this;

if (image && fromCamera) {
    obj.correctOrientation = true;
    obj.quality = 40;
}

return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    navigator.camera.getPicture(function (url) {
        var fail = function () {
            resolve(false);
        }
        window.setTimeout(function () {
            // mimeType uses window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL to get fileEntry
            that.mimeType(url).then(function (mimeObj) {
                /* 
                    mimeObj contains object like below  
                    {lastModified:'', fileType:'', fileExtension:'', name : ''}
                */
                if (mimeObj) {
                    // that.fileSystem() resolves fileSystem
                    that.fileSystem().then(function (fs) {
                        // dirName is where I want to store all myApp's media files.
                        var dirName = 'myApp/media/' + (image ? "images" : "videos") + '/';
                        that.getFile(url).then(function (fileEntry) {
                            // getFile uses window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL and returns fileEntry
                            that.moveTo(fs, fileEntry, dirName, mimeObj.name).then(function (entry) {
                                // MoveTo fill copy the same file to directory where I am manintaing files.
                                mimeObj.localURL = entry.nativeURL;
                                /* 
                                    mimeObj is failing to find extension 
                                    when user selects it from different albums. But not when user uses Camera. 
                                    So I am making again mimeType call.
                                */
                                that.mimeType(mimeObj.localURL).then(function (mimeObj) {
                                    // This gives me exact mimeObj that I need.
                                    resolve(mimeObj);
                                });
                            }, fail);
                        }, fail);
                    }, fail);
                } else {
                    resolve(false);
                }
            });
        }, 0);

    }, function (fail_message) {
        window.setTimeout(function () {
            reject(fail_message);
        }, 0);
    }, obj);
});
```